# projective and Haagerup tensor norms

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, operator-algebras

Fix $t\geqslant1$ and define $u_t=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & t}\otimes\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}+\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & -t}\otimes\pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & 1}\in\mathcal{M}_2\otimes\mathcal{M}_2$. Calculate $\|u_t\|_{\pi}$ and $\|u_t\|_h$, where these are the projective and the Haagerup tensor norms, respectively.

Comment: By "projective norm" do you mean the operator space projective norm, right?

Comment: Actually ``projective norm'' means the Banach space projective tensor norm.